# Keras - better training log output format

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Typically we have the following output log format in Keras (please follow the given link below; unable to upload image file). Is there any better way to visualize the training log format such as tabular format or graph format? What I've noticed, in ``PyTorch`or`Fast.ai` these things are much more clean to observe. So, I am looking is there has any better way to visualize the output log format?

Similar to this: (couldn't post images)
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13721

Comment: You can check tensorboard. Also, keras `fit` function returns a History object, which you can play around with...

Comment: Also keras history output can feed a pandas DataFrame: pandas.DataFrame(your_model.fit(...).history)

Comment: @LuisSobrecueva hmm, promising approach. In addition, I am hoping to visualize the progress of the model at each epoch too. Like: `epoch 1: loss - acc - val_loss - val_acc` - where all the values will dynamically improving along with row by row. Each row contains each epoch history record.